# What technology to deploy RESTful Server with SQL+COM capability

Tags: sql-server, rest, com, server

We're developing a cloud based web application for customer management. One of the main goals i the capability to connect to different local applications on the customer endpoint.

As example, we don't want to have a customer database in out application, the customer should be able to search within his local ERP system right away.

What we need is not much. Only a client on the customers server with access to the local SQL server as well as the COM model.

But as webdevelopers and mainly going with PHP the question came up, what technology we should use?

I've got two approaches in mind:

NodeJS
Lightweight, Javascript and with the Express and winole32 extension we should have everything we need. But the deployment and installation as a service seems to be a bit wacky.

C# .Net Web API
Also a good approach I guess since the client servers are allways windows. But is there a way without IIS?

Or do you have something completely different in mind? It should be very fast and compact. So its basically just a RESTservice that can be deployed with ease.

Thanks for your inputs and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> C# .Net Web API Also a good approach I guess since the client servers are 
>   allways windows. But is there a way without IIS

It is called OWIN and it is properly documented (web api self host is a good keyword) and works like a charm. Using that on various services to expose an API into the service.

Comment: Do I get that right, I can compile my "Server" in the end and I'll be able to run it as a windows service? So I end up with some kind of "myServer.exe" without any dependencies?

Comment: No, not without any dependencies. You will have to have the .NET framework installed and you will have to have a good number of other DLL's available (in your .exe folder, i.e. you can install them via your installer). But that "is it".